# Staruml component diagram UML 2.0 notation

Tags: uml, notation, staruml

Component diagram uses UML1.0 notation for 'component instance'.
Is there a support for UML 2.0 version with stereotype and small icon in the top right corner?

Answer (score 1):

I have found and an answer on [this site](https://coderanch.com/t/664602/certification/create-UML-compliant-Component-diagram).

To make it short... we can change notation with right click on the component and selecting
Format > Stereotype Display > Decoration with Label